# JSON object to eloquent object?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

With this function:

```
public function getArticleQuantity(Article $article){
    return $this->articles->where('id', $article->id);
}
```

I get back this JSON array with just one object:

```
[
   {
      "id":630,
      "name":"Dario Lueilwitz",
      "pivot":{
         "article_quantity":3
      }
   }
]
```

So i can't get the data in **pivot->article_quantity**, should i use another method or may i convert this JSON response in an eloquent object?

Comment: off topic: you should do `return $this->articles()->where('id', $article->id)->get();` that way you only get the required models from the database and not all of them to then filter on the collection.

Comment: Actually it returns the exact same json string

Comment: yes, that's why I said it's off topic. It returns the same JSON but in a more performant way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

In case someone gets in trouble that's the correct way, i think:

```
public function getArticleQuantity(Article $article){
    return $this->articles()->where('article_id', $article->id)->first()->pivot->article_quantity;
}
```

Comment: You should check if `first()` returns object

Comment: @musamba mark as correct please